# C# Json Parse Object

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net

I have a C# method returning a list. However, when displaying the list on the webpage, the serialized object is wrapped in brackets and quotes. I would like to parse this object using Newtonsoft (Json.Parse) to give it a cleaner look. However, I am unsure of how to deserialize the code in its current state. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
    public Response<List<CurrentData>> GetCurrentData()
    {

        Response<List<CurrentData>> re = new Response<List<CurrentData>>();

        try
        {

            DataTable dt = SqlClass.GetDataTable(Config.GetConnectionString("master"), "exec dbo.GetCurrentData");

            re.Response = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
            {
                return new CurrentData()
                {
                    Id = r.Field<string>("ID"),
                    Date = r.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                    Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
                    Source= r.Field<string>("Source") //needs to be parsed
                };
            }).ToList();                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            re.ResponseCode = -1;
            re.ErrorDescription.Add(ex.Message);
        }

        return re;


    }
```

Comment: What is your code to display the list on the webpage?

Comment: I'm using a kendo table

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm You mean this Json.Parse?

Comment: That's not make things cleaner. Show example of "the serialized object is wrapped in brackets and quotes".  And for what purpose you need "cleaner look"?

Comment: It is displaying on the webapge as { "current data" : "data data data"}

Comment: Please explain what is the value of `r.Field<string>("Source")` and what value do you want?